# no matching function for call to Structured_Matrix::Structured_Matrix()

Tags: c++

I am a student needing help with an error on my assignment, we are currently learning about inheritance and polymorphism.

Symmetric_Matrix is a derived class of Structured_Matrix

Symmetric.cc, this is where the error is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "./Symmetric_Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

Symmetric_Matrix::Symmetric_Matrix (int n, double value)
{
   if (n == 0)
    {
      rows = 0;
      cols = 0;
      num = nullptr;
    }
   else 
  {
     rows = n;
     cols = n;
     num = new double [rows * cols];

     for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
      *(num + i) = value;
  }
}
```

Symmetric.h

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef SYMMETRIC_MATRIX_H
#define SYMMETRIC_MATRIX_H
#include "./Structured_Matrix.h"
#include "./Symmetric_Matrix.cc"

using namespace std; 

class Symmetric_Matrix : public Structured_Matrix
{
  public:
    Symmetric_Matrix (int n, double value = 0.0);
};
#endif
```

Structured.h

```
#ifndef STRUCTURED_MATRIX_H
#define STRUCTURED_MATRIX_H
#include <iostream>

class Structured_Matrix 
{
public:
 Structured_Matrix(int n, double value = 0.0);
};
#endif
```

Comment: You're constructing a `Structured_Matrix` in some code not shown without any arguments. But you don't have a default constructor defined to handle that.

Comment: If base object does not have default constructor then you need to invoke base object constructor in the derived class constructor. It probably should've been `Symmetric_Matrix::Symmetric_Matrix (int n, double value): Structured_Matrix{n, value}`.

Comment: Note that your matrix classes can be initialized or instantiated using implicit conversion. Like for example `Symmetric_Matrix matrix = 5;` is valid, but looks kind of weird and makes the code harder to understand. If you don't want a *converting or conversion constructor* then you need to make all constructors taking one single argument `explicit`.

Answer (score 0):

`Structure_Matrix` contains no default constructor but here

```
Symmetric_Matrix::Symmetric_Matrix (int n, double value)
{
    ...
}
```

You are using a default constructor, because you don't call any other constructor explizitly. You most likely want to call the provided constructor.

```
Symmetric_Matrix::Symmetric_Matrix (int n, double value)
: Structured_Matrix(n, value)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Structured_Matrix::Structured_Matrix()` is the *default* (no-argument) constructor of `Structured_Matrix`.

This `Structured_Matrix` default constructor will be invoked as part of the `Symmetric_Matrix` construction.

If you want to explicitly invoke another `Structured_Matrix` constructor (like the one you have defined) then you need to do it in your `Symmetric_Matrix` constructor initalizer list:

```
Symmetric_Matrix::Symmetric_Matrix (int n, double value)
    : Structured_Matrix(n, value)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or you need to provide a (possibly protected) `Structured_Matrix` default constructor:

```
class Structured_Matrix 
{
public:
 Structured_Matrix(int n, double value = 0.0);

protected:
 Structured_Matrix() = default;  // Defaulted default constructor
};
```